# Is it possible to create user programmatically in ActiveMQ?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I want to create user for ActiveMQ programmatically in C# without changing anything in `activemq.xml` file. So is this possible to create?

And If yes, will it be possible to assign rights to user programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, you must configure the broker with new user roles and credentials, it would be a huge security issue to allow client code to do something like this, plus the JMS and NMS APIs don't have anything remotely like management capabilities in then.